# How to remember and recall cursor position?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, cursor-movement, cursor

Imaging I'm editing some code, and I found a few words that I would like to paste at the current cursor position elsewhere in the file. I will go to them, yank them, but then how do I return back to the original location to paste them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use explicit marks with `m` normal command:

1. `ma` -- mark position into register `a`
2. goto anywhere
3. return to the marked position with `` `a ``

- `:h mark-motions`
- `:h registers`

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was after, I will dispense the ticks in a couple of days

Answer (score 3):

If you jump to the interesting part with a motion, you could use `:h <c-o>` to jump back where you were.

Another possible approach is to copy the line with `:h :copy` / `:t`, like so:

```
:/pattern/t.
```

This will search for the next line matching 'pattern' and copy it (`t`) under the current line (`.`).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `<C-o>`, there is the single-quote and backtick mark: `''` and `` ` `` go the line and line + column from before the last jump I believe.